# Pluralization issue in the review queue - received vote count tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, tooltips, plurals

There is a pluralization issue in the review queue - received vote count tooltip. For the 1 vote, it is displayed as 1 vote**s**

> This community-specific close reason received 1 vote**s**

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: 1 votes]

Comment: <mandatory deprecated meme reference here>. Can someone tell me why to this day *all* occurrences of a "number followed by a word" (*not* determined by regex) are not wrapped in a simple utility consisting of *just one ternary operator*?

Comment: @OlegValter Because you don't always pluralise stuff after numbers e.g. *"You cannot upvote an answer after reaching the 30 vote limit"* - notice not vote**s**. (example is artificial, not sure what cases of this there are across the network)

Comment: @Nick - I didn't mean there aren't valid cases where pluralization should not be applied, I just cannot fathom why every occurrence of number-followed-by-word is not wrapped in a utility (that can be configurable `(n > 1 && !ignore ? "s" : "")` so that the "pluralizaition bug" keeps coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems the bug had been fixed sometime before.

Now, the vote count tooltip has been corrected and the current tooltip is below:

> This community-specific close reason received 1 vote

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image]